# Posting parameters to IFrame without using src + asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using a Webpage and its contains a webuser control. The webuser control contains an IFrame which is pointing to a different webpage.

Issue is i need to pass some parameters from user control to IFrame ,so that i can 
use them in target page server side or in load event.

Comment: in your usercontrol, create a public property which get and set the iframe.src attribute. i don't think you can do it without using .src attribute.

Comment: I found some examples to post data using form submit, but the posted values are not avaible when i try to fetch them in target aspx load method

Comment: Why not pass the parameters in the query string of the src attribute? Your Page_Load can read that then

Comment: due to the length issue.some values are large.